# Android - center of element (image) on top of another element

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create view where one element's vertical center (ImageView - black circle) is exactly on top/start of another element (LinearLayout - red box). In other words - half of black circle should be above red layout and half of it should be inside. What is the easiest way to do that? Is it possible to achieve in xml?

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/red"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/red_block">
           SOME OTHER VIEWS INSIDE
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/some_circle"
        android: CENTER_ON_TOP_OF_RED_BLOCK??? />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question [Divide Layout in two parts and center Image in the middle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33595699/divide-layout-in-two-parts-and-center-image-in-the-middle)

Comment: Unfortunately no. In your case, there are two equal layouts and circle/image can be just centered in main layout. In my case circle cannot be centered in main layout, because red layout's height is not half of parent's height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's time to use [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/constraint-layout).

You can let the vertical center of black circle align the top of red block by this two attribute

> app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/red_block"
> app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/red_block"

**xml:**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/red_block"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/red"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent">
        <!--SOME OTHER VIEWS INSIDE-->
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/some_circle"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/red_block"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/red_block" /> 
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**preview:**

[image]